# Unable to query using only the rangeKey

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynogels

I just started working on DynamoDB so please forgive me if the following seems like a dumb mistake.

- I have a model with a `hashKey` and a `rangeKey`. Let's name these as HASH and RANGE respectively.
- A global secondary index: `GlobalIndex` is added to the model as well.

Now what I want is to get the list of records by `rangeKey`. I don't want to use the `scan` operation since it impacts the performance. I am unable to achieve this with the `query` operation. 
Trying to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38814345/5284640) with [dynogels](https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels).

Any kind of help would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Dynogels: 9.0.0
Node: 6.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake on my end. The index has the same hash key and range key as the table. 
The GitHub issue thread for the same: https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels/issues/137

Comment: Please don't post [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/211183).  Post the actual answer, citing sources.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sure. Added a description. Thanks